# Bitcoind installation on ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind

How would I go about installing bitcoind to a specific directory in ubuntu?
https://gist.github.com/rjmacarthy/b56497a81a6497bfabb1
I'm following that instruction but it downloads to .bitcoin by default and I want to change to somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE!

You need to add the `-datadir={dir}` parameter to your command line.

A full list of command line options is available if you key `bitcoind --help`